# Remove QUERY_STRING from URL only for /index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, query-string

I would like to remove the query string from the URL using mod_rewrite (.htaccess), but only for `/index.php` (and not `/`).

For example, `http://www.example.org/index.php?foo=bar` should redirect to `http://www.example.org/index.php`, but `http://www.example.org/?foo=bar` should be left alone.

This is my current sutup:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

It works, but not with the limitation I want (i.e. it still removes the query string even when `index.php` is not in the URL. I think this may have to do with REQUEST_URI realising that `/` is being internally redirected to `/index.php`, but I can't be sure.

As a side question, I would have a lot easier time working this stuff out if I could work out what value was being used REQUEST_URI, is there an easy way to log this somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this lines to your httpd.conf to see what's going on

```
RewriteLog /path/to/log
RewriteLogLevel 5
```